# Which tables in Moodle are safe to be truncated?

Tags: caching, mysql, moodle

For the purposes of dumping a Moodle db for backups, which tables can be exported as structure only (that is, they are cache tables safe to be truncated) ?

I don't want to export cached data as the backups are to be kept in a revision control system.

Thank you.